# What does lambda::_1 mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have the following source code that i am trying to understand.

```
lambda::bind(&internal::on_accept, lambda::_1)
```

What does `lambda::_1` mean?

Comment: `_1` is valid as the name of a variable.

Comment: It's a `lambda` named `_1`.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders

Comment: [This](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#lambda.placeholders), probably.

Comment: Well, where did you see this code? Can you look up what `lambda` is? Is there documentation? You tell us.

Comment: @mister: There's no such thing in standard C++ (incl. C++11). Without relevant context, this is not a valid C++ question.

Comment: Come on guys, this is most likely referring to boost's lambda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lambda` is either a class, or a namespace. `_1` is a member of that class/namespace. It could be either a variable, or a function.

There is no class by the name of `lambda` in the standard library.

You can find out more about `lambda` and its members by looking at its definition, and documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Missing context here, but from experience with `bind`, I assume that _1 is used to refer to the first argument that will be used when calling the function. Calling `func("abc")` would result in calling `on_accept("abc")`. Bind can be used to remap arguments and additional parameters, for example `lambda::bind(&internal::on_accept, lambda::_1, true, lambda::_2)` would result in a function that when called with `foo(1, 2)` would result in a call to `on_accept(1, true, 2)`